# hadoop showing map reduce percentages running twice

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running Apache's Hadoop, and using the grep example provided by that installation. **I'm wondering why map reduce percentages show up running twice?** I thought they only had to run once; which makes me doubt my understanding of map reduce. I looked it up (http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/125ay1eazq/map-reduce-percentage-seems-running-twice) but there really wasn't an explanation and this link was for MongoDB.

```
hduser@ubse1:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar grep /user/hduser/grep /user/hduser/grep-output4 ".*woe is me.*"
```

I'm running this on a project gutenberg .txt file. The output file is correct.

Here is the output for running the command if needed:

```
12/08/06 06:56:57 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/08/06 06:56:57 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/08/06 06:56:57 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/08/06 06:56:58 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201208030925_0011
12/08/06 06:56:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/08/06 06:57:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/08/06 06:57:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201208030925_0011
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 30
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=31034
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=2
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=2
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=11233
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=5592666
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=391
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=281
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=5592862
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=65331
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=391
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=287
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=124796
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=287
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=10
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=265
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=336404480
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=7040
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=5590193
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=196
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=5
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=5
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=5
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=5
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=464568320
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=5
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1539559424
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=5
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/08/06 06:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201208030925_0012
12/08/06 06:57:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/08/06 06:57:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/08/06 06:58:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201208030925_0012
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 30
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=15432
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=1
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=14264
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=391
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=235
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=281
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=505
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=42985
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=235
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=281
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=5
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
12/08/06 06:58:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=10
```

**EDIT** Driver Class for Grep: 
**Grep.java**

```
/**
* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
* or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
* distributed with this work for additional information
* regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
* to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
* "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
* with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/
package org.apache.hadoop.examples;

import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

/* Extracts matching regexs from input files and counts them. */
public class Grep extends Configured implements Tool {
 private Grep() {} // singleton

 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
 if (args.length < 3) {
 System.out.println("Grep <inDir> <outDir> <regex> [<group>]");
 ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.out);
 return -1;
 }

 Path tempDir =
 new Path("grep-temp-"+
 Integer.toString(new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));

 JobConf grepJob = new JobConf(getConf(), Grep.class);

 try {

 grepJob.setJobName("grep-search");
 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(grepJob, args[0]);

 grepJob.setMapperClass(RegexMapper.class);
 grepJob.set("mapred.mapper.regex", args[2]);
 if (args.length == 4)
 grepJob.set("mapred.mapper.regex.group", args[3]);

 grepJob.setCombinerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
 grepJob.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);

 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(grepJob, tempDir);
 grepJob.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
 grepJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 grepJob.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

 JobClient.runJob(grepJob);

 JobConf sortJob = new JobConf(getConf(), Grep.class);
 sortJob.setJobName("grep-sort");

 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(sortJob, tempDir);
sortJob.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);

 sortJob.setMapperClass(InverseMapper.class);

 sortJob.setNumReduceTasks(1); // write a single file
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(sortJob, new Path(args[1]));
 sortJob.setOutputKeyComparatorClass // sort by decreasing freq
 (LongWritable.DecreasingComparator.class);

 JobClient.runJob(sortJob);
 }
 finally {
 FileSystem.get(grepJob).delete(tempDir, true);
 }
 return 0;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Grep(), args);
 System.exit(res);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file there are the statistics of two jobs: `job: job_201208030925_0011` and `job: job_201208030925_0012`. The percentages belong to these two jobs, hence there are 2 map progress percentages.

Comment: Why are there two jobs though? What hadoop doing in the first and second jobs respectively? How is it splitting up the work and why is it splitting up the work for a simple grep on 1 file?

Comment: add the implementation of your driver class - class where you set up the job and start it.

Comment: what you added us the driver class. 
Look here: JobClient.runJob(grepJob); ... few lines lower .... JobClient.runJob(sortJob);

So you run 2 jobs

Comment: Yes, but what are the differences between these two jobs? Obviously one is a grepJob and one is a sortJob, but what does that mean? Is grepJob performing the greps on the files, and sortJob just writing it to an output file?

Comment: This is a completely different question from the original one. However, the grep job is searching for a pattern and it outputs instances of that pattern and their frequencies, in a SequenceFile. 
The sort jobs sorts this file in descending order of the frequencies.